# Smooth functions can not be non-polynomial at one point

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, analytic-functions

I am studying the classic problem [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial) about Baire's Category theorem.

One of the remarks is that if $f$ is smooth and not a polynomial,
$$X = \big\{x : \forall(a,b)\ni x, f|_{(a,b)} \text{ is not a polynomial}\big \}$$
has no isolated points. How could I show that the smooth function $f$ can not be non-polynomial at one (or isolated) point.

Intuitively a function $f$ can be non-polynomial at a single isolated point $x$ if there is a corner in some derivative $f^{(n)}$ at $x$. And when the function is smooth, this can not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If false, then there is $\delta > 0$ such that $(x,x+\delta]\cap X = \emptyset.$ Because $x + \delta \not \in X,$ there is an open interval $I$ centered at  $x + \delta$ such that $f$ equals a polynomial $p$ in $I.$ We can assume the left end point of $I$ is greater than $x.$ Then there is an open interval $J$ centered at this endpoint such that $f$ equals a polynomial $q$ in $J.$ This forces $p=q$ everywhere. Why? Because they both equal $f$ in $I\cap J,$ which is open and non-empty, and two polynomials that agree on an infinite set are equal everywhere. It follows that there is a polynomial that equals $f$ on $I\cup J.$

This process can be continued, obtaining larger open intervals on which $f$ is a polynomial. In fact this will lead to one polynomial that equals $f$ on $(x,x+\delta]$ (that needs proving, but I'll leave it for now). This implies there exists $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $f^{(m)} \equiv 0$ on $(x,x+\delta].$ By continuity, $f^{(m)}(x) = 0$ as well.

The same argument applies to the left of $x,$ where we conclude there is $\epsilon >0$ and $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $f^{(n)} \equiv 0$ on $[x-\epsilon,x].$ Let $N = \max (m,n).$ Then $f^{(N)} \equiv 0$ on an open interval containing $x,$ and therefore $f$ is a polynomial of degree $< N$ on this interval. That's a contradiction, giving the result.

Comment: In the first paragraph, we do not have to choose the interval with the end points at the center right? As long as the end point is contained in the open interval.

Comment: Yes, certainly.